# MySQLdb connection error, cannot solve by setting localhost as '127.0.0.1'

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I installed `mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` on Python 3.5.I am using windows 64.
When I use

```
MySQLdbconnect(host="127.0.0.1", port=3306)
```

I receive the following error:

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)")
```

Does anyone have the same situation?

Comment: You may need to GRANT permissions to connect to that database from localhost using the given username and password.

Comment: Is the MySQL server running, and listening on localhost? That error means that the network connection was refused.

Comment: I tried putting user and passwd for logging in my PC that doesn;t work.